# How to display GIF animation on click coordinates on screen

Tags: android, xml, animation, onclick

I wanted to display this GIF animation:
http://www.123gifs.eu/free-gifs/baseball/baseball-0106.gif

I want to display this animation wherever the user clicks on the screen. Also I only want this to happen if the user has clicked on a certain ImageButton. For example:

```
View.OnClickListener batlistener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //display GIF wherever user touches
        }
    };
    bbatsource.setOnClickListener(batlistener);
```

So, the user clicks on the button, then on the user's second click, the GIF is shown wherever he clicks on he screen.

Thanks!